How to Persist Bitmap Image State Across Navigation in Jetpack Compose with CameraX?
I implemented a camera feature using Jetpack Compose. Here is my current implementation:
ViewModel:
var originImageUri = mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)
    private set

View:
var capturedImageUri by pixelConvertViewModel.originImageUri

Get URI:
LaunchedEffect(navController.currentBackStackEntry) {
    navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<Uri>("capturedImageUri")?.let {
        println("capturedImageUri is $it")
        // capturedImageUri = it
        pixelConvertViewModel.saveOriginUrl(it)
    }
}

When I take a picture and return to the current screen, capturedImageUri has a value momentarily but then becomes null. Visually, the image appears for a moment and then disappears. If I reopen the camera screen and return, the image appears for a moment and then disappears again. The capturedImageUri can be printed but then becomes null.
I am using Jetpack Compose's NavController. How can I ensure that pixelImageBitmap is persisted?

I have try:
var capturedImageUri by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }

init it in view but nothing change,Image can be display,but uri has been null,when I update view,the image dismiss
